# GTK 3.0 Evolution css theme gtk.css

Tags: css, gtk3

I have looked all over the place and can't seem to find the CSS ID's for Evolution..

I want to be able to customize the colors in Evolution. I have found some CSS tags that were changing sizes but nothing to do with unread email.

My primary goal is to have unread email have a different font color... Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: To be clearer.. I can add the following changes to my gtk.css and change font sizes in the left panel..
EMailSidebar.view {
  font-size: 5px;
}
so what changes unread mail?

Comment: Use the GTK inspector (start Evolution with `GTK_DEBUG=interactive` in the environment.) It may not be possible to do what you want, but the inspector will help you find out.

Comment: I had to apply a class to the MessageList ECanvas to get my styles to apply.. but this still does no good because the bold 'unread' state is applied somewhere else I believe. Current;y for this container.. font-weight:normal.. and if I apply a temp style (font-weight:bold), then all mail is bold no matter what. This tells me I am in the right section, I just cannot figure out where this font-weight:bold is being applied. Any suggestions?

Comment: just a note to add.. I did find this theme https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1013750/ which did change Evolution mail but it only changed the font color of all mail and not just the unread mail.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

create file called gtk.css in directory ~/.config/gtk-3.0

Edit gtk.css with the following:

```
MessageList,* {
        -MessageList-new-mail-bg-color: SteelBlue;
}
```

save changes made to gtk.css file and restart evolution mail client

Comment: Hi. How do you get to that attribute name? Although I can change other elements following this general advice (eg. background color for email previews under dark theme), setting a color for the attribute you specified changes nothing.

Using GTK_DEBUG allows me to inspect down to MessageList, but not any further.

Comment: Ok, found the attribute in the `evolution` source:

https://github.com/GNOME/evolution/blob/38964d1de0ea42364c2a1136627a97472cc7d4f6/src/mail/message-list.c#L2043

but I'm using `evolution-ews` (only managed to get version 3.18.5.2 working with my Exchange setup). Looking for the appropriate source to dig for the attribute name, maybe it was changed at some point in between these versions.

Comment: Never mind, following the git blame found that the ability to modify this attribute was added in a newer version.

https://github.com/GNOME/evolution/commit/8a549baf157c02bb61396997e89a5f77c7240943

Will try updating to that.

Answer (score 2):

If you prefer to change the font and not the background, you can use the foreground attribute to change just the text color.

Note the change from bg to fg below:

```
MessageList,* {
        -MessageList-new-mail-fg-color: SteelBlue;
}
```

This is currently working for me on Evolution 3.36.5-0ubuntu1

As stated above, file location:
~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css

If you clone the source code from github, the code is located in:
evolution/src/mail/message-list.c

Comment: Nice, thank you for this addition! I ended up theming using this option.